# std::bind and different signature of calling binded function

Tags: c++, bind, visual-studio-2010

Please, explain, why in the following code there is no error:

```
void f()
{
}

void h()
{
    std::bind(f)(42);
}
```

Why compiler doesn't complain about redundant parameter in std::bind while binding function f?  And if it shouldn't, please explain why this can be useful.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It might be useful to know for someone trying to answer the question.

Comment: doesn't it? g++ complains and won't compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is conformant. The arguments that you pass to the result of bind are only used if needed.

---

Using the terminology from the standard: `u` is the result of `std::bind(f, t1, ..., tN)`.

*Approximately* speaking:

When `u(u1, u2, ..., uM)` is called, `f` is called as `f(v1, ..., vN)`, where the values of `vi` are determined by the following algorithm:

```
//N is the N from `std::bind(f, t1, ..., tN)`
For each i in 1 to N:
    if (ti is a reference wrapper) vi is the unwrapped version of t1
    if (ti is a bind_expression) vi is the result of calling ti with u1, ..., uM
    if (ti is a placeholder) vi is uj (where j is is_placeholder<decltype(ti)>::value)
    otherwise vi is ti
```